# RPM package prerequisites

Tags: c++, rpm, packaging

I have a driver RPM package which installs the basic driver and after that another package for installing it's utility programs. The driver rpm checks all the prerequisites needed to install it. And utility have a prerequisite as the driver rpm.

Is it enough to check for driver rpm and ignore all other per-requisites in utility rpm because they are already checked when the driver is installed.

Is it okay for RPM packaging ?

Comment: Not sure completely what you are asking, but basically no, utility package might have different prerequisite (just because it contains different binaries) which driver package might not have.

Comment: I have checked those dependencies, so all the dependencies are covered when the driver package installs.   The only possibility is after driver installed and when package dependencies are broken outside the inspection of package manager and then when trying to install utility package. In that case neither utility program works because driver would not be working as well.

Comment: RPMs for drivers are a real pain. The official Fedora stance is [don't do it](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines#No_External_Kernel_Modules).

What happens when the user updates their kernel? Are you going to make them reinstall your driver every time? Because your modules will be in `/lib/modules/old_kernel_version/` and not where you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that.

If you are sure that all the dependencies of the utility rpm will be met when the driver rpm is installed, then checking for the driver alone should be sufficient.